# How to execute an action when a combined animation ended?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to the world of Dojo so this is probably something dumb which is giving me a hard time.

I have the following code (stripped of irrelevant stuff):

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/fx", "dojo/on"],
    function (declare, fx, on) {
        return declare(null, {
            executeTransition: function (continuation) {
                var animation = fx.combine([
                    fx.slideTo({
                        duration: 1200,
                        node: this.node1, // node1 will be a valid node at the moment of execution
                        left: -this.node1.offsetWidth
                    }),
                    fx.slideTo({
                        duration: 1200,
                        node: this.node2, // node2 will be a valid node at the moment of execution
                        left: 0
                    })
                ]);

                on(animation, "End", continuation);

                animation.play();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

When executing my code as it is, the `on` line fails saying `Uncaught Error: Target must be an event emitter`. But being an animation, should it be an event emitter already?

Some background research I did trying to solve my problem:

The [reference guide to dojo.fx](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/fx/combine.html#dojo-fx-combine) treats the result of `fx.combine` as any other animation. The [API reference for dojo.fx](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/fx) only states that it returns an instance.

Regardless, the [Dojo 1.8 animation tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/animation/) has the very same example I'm trying to execute, except that it later wraps the result of fx.combine in a fx.chain (which I do not need -- or do I?).

So, my question is: **Using Dojo 1.8, how do I run two animations in parallel and execute some code when they're done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question, I decided to investigate.  I found that the, *"Target must be an event emitter"* error only occurs when trying to capture the **onEnd** event from a combined animation.  It does not occur for chained animations.

After some digging around I noticed that combined animations seemed to have a _connects property, which suggested it was using the old depreciated ["dojo/_base/connect"](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/connect.html) functionality.  This is probably a bug in Dojo (or rather code that got missed in the most recent upgrades).  Had a look on the [Dojo Trac](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/) but not found anything yet, will probably open a new ticket for this one.

There are two work-arounds that I can think of:

1. Use ["dojo/_base/connect"](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/connect.html)

   ```
   connect.connect(animation, "onEnd", function(){
       // connect == dojo/base/connect
   })
   ```
2. Connect to the onEnd event directly (or use ["dojo/aspect"](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html#dojo-aspect))

   ```
   animation.onEnd(function(){
   });
   ```

Neither of these ways are ideal, as you'll probably have to change your code to a [dojo/on](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html) version at some future date.

**Edit:** Looks like someone else has already reported this as a bug, [see here](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16305).

Comment: Thank you so much. My first approach was to use the method directly, but that didn't work. The animation object does not expose an onEnd method. However, using dojo/aspect did work (why, if the method is not there?).

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't use the onEnd() method directly; it seemed to work fine for me.  It could be something to do with when the method is being created.  Dojo/aspect is perhaps capturing this but it isn't available yet then you try to use it outside of dojo/aspect.  The reason for dojo/on not working though, is actually a bug, so I'd keep an eye on things, any work-around now is likely to break later on when the issue is fixed.  Perhaps, try wrapping a dojo/on clause in a try...catch with a catch fallback to your dojo/aspect code.  That way when the issue is fixed you'll be using dojo/on.